# PyQt5 call function when click on QListWidgetItem

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

How can I make sure that the do_something() function is called only when QListWidgetItem "Item 1" is clicked, but not QListWidgetItem "Item 2"?

In the implementation below, do_something() function is called each time I click on either of the items.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListWidget, QHBoxLayout, QListWidgetItem
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_widget = QListWidget()
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.list_widget)
        self.list_widget.insertItem(1, QListWidgetItem("Item 1"))
        self.list_widget.insertItem(2, QListWidgetItem("Item 2"))
        self.list_widget.itemClicked.connect(self.do_something)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.show()

    def do_something(self):
        print("It was clicked on item 1")


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to obtain the row of the pressed item and verify that it is 0:

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot

# ...

@pyqtSlot("QListWidgetItem*")
def do_something(self, item):
    if self.list_widget.row(item) == 0:
        print("It was clicked on item 1")
```